# If two finite algebraic structures are surjective images of each other, then they are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be some algebraic structure (a monoid, a group, a vector space etc) and suppose $\varphi$ is some homomorphism. Suppose $|A| = |\varphi(A)|$ as sets. If $|A|$ is finite, then $\varphi$ must be injective?

Is this true, I guess yes, but I cannot find a reference? I can find a reference to a somehow related fact, that if $\varphi : A \to B$ is injective and $|A| = |B|$, then $\varphi(A) = B$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404639/an-injection-between-finite-sets-of-equal-size-must-be-a-bijection). I guess from this a proof could be derived, namely for each $y \in \varphi(A)$ choose some $a \in A$ with $\varphi(a) = y$ (i.e. choose some element from the preimage), by this we get an injective function from $\varphi(A)$ to $A$, hence it is surjective. But this implies that $|\varphi^{-1}(y)| = 1$ for each $y \in \varphi(A)$, for otherwise the constructed function would not be surjective.

I find this fact useful, in the spirit of this [blog post](https://lydianrain.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/the-%E2%80%9Cinjectivity-implies-surjectivity%E2%80%9D-trick/), for example it allows one to derive, that if $A$ and $B$ are finite and we have surjective homomorphism onto each other, then $A \cong B$ (something like a Schröder-Bernstein for algebraic structures in the finite setting). But I was wondering why if such basic conclusion could be drawn, it is nowhere mentioned, but maybe I have overlooked something?

Comment: If $A$ and $\varphi(A)$ have the same (finite) cardinality, then as a function of sets, $\varphi$ must be a bijection onto its image. This has nothing to do with the algebraic structure.

Comment: Um if $\phi$ is a *homomorphism* by definition it is injective.  But if you meant simply $\phi$ is a *function* and $|A| = |\phi(A)|$ is finite, than yes, $\phi$ is a bijection regardless of algebraic structure of A.

Comment: @fleablood, why is a homomorphism injective ? :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the algebraic structures you are considering, an isomorphism is the same thing as a homomorphism which is a bijection.

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between finite sets, and $X$ and $Y$ have the same number of elements, then $f$ is  (i) bijective $\iff$ (ii) injective $\iff$ (iii) surjective.  Putting these two facts together gives you what you want.

If you were wondering why this property of functions isn't mentioned, it actually is a famous mathematical principle!  The general fact I mentioned about $f$ is a version of what is called the Pigeonhole Principle.