# Equality of finite sets with $A \subseteq B$ and $|A|=|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I was just curious for finite sets $A,B$ if $A \subseteq B$ and $|A|=|B|$ then $A=B$. 
I attempted the proof however I feel I'm missing something.

**Proof**. To show $A=B$ it remains to show that $B\subseteq A$. Consider the set $B\setminus A$. Since $|A|=|B|$ and $A\subseteq B$, if follows that $B\setminus A$ is empty (How do I argue that this is true?). Hence, $B\subseteq A$. Finally, $A=B$.

Is my proof correct? What are some alternative ways?

Comment: It's true for finite sets.

Comment: Indeed $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: You can write $B=A\sqcup (B\setminus A)$, a disjoint union. Then $|B|=|A|+|B\setminus A|$, so $|B\setminus A|=0$ as all cardinalities in question are finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Claim:* If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets such that $A \subseteq B$ and $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert$, then  $A = B$.

*Proof:* Since $A \subseteq B$, there is a natural injection $\iota \colon A \to B$ defined by $\iota(x) = x$ for every $x \in A$. It is well known that [an injection between finite sets of equal cardinality must be a bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404639/an-injection-between-finite-sets-of-equal-size-must-be-a-bijection). Therefore, $\iota$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$ that is nothing but the identity function. Hence, $A = B$.