# If $H$ is a finite subset of $G$, then check if function is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was doing Algebra and ran into a theorem on subgroups and was stuck on one part of the proof:
The author states that if $H$ is a finite, non-empty subset of $G$, and is closed under multiplication, it is a subgroup.
To prove this, he uses this: Let $ x \in H$. Take the mapping $f:H \rightarrow H$ to be such that $f(y)=xy$ for all $y\in H$.

I couldn't seem to wrap around why this function is surjective, as the author states, because of the fact of H being finite. 
Please help, any clue will be appreciated!

Comment: What  if $H$ doesn't contain the identity element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f(y)=f(z)$. Then $xy=xz \implies y=x^{-1}xy=x^{-1}xz =z \implies f$ is injective. Since $f$ is an injection between finite sets of equal cardinality, $f$ must also be a surjection.

A relevant link: [An injection between finite sets of equal size must be a bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404639/an-injection-between-finite-sets-of-equal-size-must-be-a-bijection)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!