# Injective homomorphism between two finite groups with the same order

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I want to show given two groups $G,H$ and the homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ injective with $\text{ord}(G)=\text{ord}(H)<\infty$, then $f$ is bijective.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Consider $G$ and $H$ as sets. Can you define an inverse? Now show that it is a homomorphism of groups (easy).

Comment: Note that you do not need to use group theory anywhere to answer this question. An injective map between finite sets of equal size must be a bijection, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404639/an-injection-between-finite-sets-of-equal-size-must-be-a-bijection)

Comment: @TastyRomeo yes, but sometimes you can have a set-inverse that is not a morphism in the category you are looking at.

Comment: The question didn't ask for the inverse to be a homomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Since $f$ is injective, we know that $H$ contains a "copy" of $G$. Namely, the image $\text{im}(f) \le H$ is a subgroup of $H$ isomorphic to $G$ (why?). But if $G$ and $H$ are the same order, what can we conclude about $\text{im}(f)$ and $H$?

Comment: Aaah, of course. The image of a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a subgroup of H, and if $f$ is injevtive, then $f:G\rightarrow \text{im}(G)$ is bijective (and still a homomorphism) and if a subgroup of a group has the same order, it has to be the group itself. Thank you very much.